# pg_dump/pg_restore: different PostgreSQL version, another database name, another tablespace

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, pg-dump

I am going to move a database from the old server to a new one.

- the old one runs PostgreSQL 9.1, the new one has 9.3.
- I want to change the database name.
- I want the new database to be in a dedicated tablespace (the old one is in default) - including indices, etc.

Unfortunately, I have no chance to experiment (and HDDs of the old server start to fail) so I ask for the options for pg_dump/pg_restore that would work in my case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have completed the migration with no problems.

Creating the dump is easy:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump --verbose --no-tablespaces --format=directory --file=/backup/path old_database_name
```

Restoring on a new instance: first, create a new tablespace, and a target database in that tablespace. Then import your dump like this:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_restore --verbose --dbname=new_database_name --jobs=8 /backup/path/
```

You can adjust number of concurrent jobs dependent on Your hardware - processor cores, I/O subsystem performance, etc.

Now we have all the data in another database, with different name, in a dedicated tablespace, on a new server running newer PostgreSQL.

Comment: Used this approach once again today; unfortunately cannot upvote own post :)

Comment: worked for an upgrade from 9.4 -> 9.6 as well

Comment: I get an error pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.14) in file header. With your provided option it appears this method only works for minor postgres changes. 

I'm moving from 9.6 to 11.

Comment: @sqwale thanks for the heads up. We will be moving a couple of 9.6 databases to 12 this year (the other ones are now just event projections from a Kafka streams)

Comment: I finally managed to resolve the issue. The source DB was 9.6 so realised I needed the pg_dump to be the same version as the database I would be restoring to. Also noticed an odd situation where my postgres running was 12 but by pg_dump was still 9.6. So ensure you'r pg_dump -v returns what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using pg_dump it will dump the schema and the data.

`pg_dump -d mydb -f dump_file_name.sql`

To restore you have to `createdb` first and then restore it so, the new name issue can be solved when creating the new database.

`createdb mynewdb`

For the tablespace, you first have to create the tablespace in the newly created database.

`create tablespace 'your_tablespace' location 'your_tablespace_location'`

Then edit the dump file (dump_file_name.sql) created with pg_dump and edit `SET default_tablespace = ''` to `SET default_tablespace = 'your_tablespace'`.

Finally you can restore with:

`psql -d mynewdb -f dump_file_name.sql`

Comment: Thanks Fabrizio! So, editing sql dump is required... I thought to use directory+tar to make import fatser.

Comment: What do you mean by directory + tar? Moving the whole postgres dir? I don't think that's a good idea!

Comment: Remember that when you upgrade major versions a dump and restore is always required (as per docs)

Comment: I mean `pg_dump --format=directory.`

Comment: Oh ok! Sorry but no experience with directory format. In any case if you need to change the tablespace the plain text dump is the way to go.